# How to move a ball in a square path

Tags: java

i want to move a ball in a square path. right now it moves in a triangular like wave. i want it to behave like the image. what can i do to make this happen? thanks!

[how i want the ball to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQDrt.jpg)

this is my code atm:

public void move(int widthScreen, int heightScreen) {

```
    posX += velocityX;

    posY += velocityY;

    // Check for collisions with screen walls

    if (posX <= 0 || posX >= widthScreen - size) {

        velocityX *= -1; // Reverse horizontal velocity

    }

    if (posY <= 0 || posY >= heightScreen - size) {

        velocityY *= -1; // Reverse vertical velocity

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is moving in a triangular path because you are updating the value of the posX and posY simultaneously. If you want to move in a straight line update the only one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If i only update one position it will be only moving in that position in a straight line. i want it to oscillate. [Like it happens in this image.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx0V5.jpg

Comment: then update your x and y positions accordingly. Like when you want to move the ball vertically make x constant and change the value of y. Similarly if you want to move the ball horizontally then make y constant and change the value of x. Be mindful on having the correct sign for velocity for the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to add coordinates in the square area (e.g. 10*10), start at a certain coordinate, set the coordinates for the ball to move up and down, and then move up or down after the ball reaches the specified coordinates.